# How can I represent this Game Owner Relationship in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, object-relational-model

I'm trying to tease out a logical problem that I'm having and I didn't know where else to ask!

I have two Objects whose relationship I'm trying to describe; the `User` and the `Game`. So, right now, I have that a `User` belongs to many `Games`, and that a `Game` belongs to many `Users`. What I'm trying to describe is the special instance when a `User` owns a `Game`. Presumably, this would simply be a column in the table for the `owner_id`. I am, however, struggling to establish how I can represent this in Eloquent. Do I need to create a new Object for the Game owner? Or can I use some kind of User role to describe this?

**Game**

```
class Game extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $guarded = array();
    public static $rules = array();

    // Game belongsToMany User
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

    // Need to identify the owner user.
}
```

**User**

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = array();
    public static $rules = array();

    // User belongsToMany Game
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game');
    }
}
```

I'm having difficulty even figuring out how to ask this in a clear and concise way, so if there's any more detail needed, please don't hesitate to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is thid table: games_owners. This is a migration schema for it:

```
Schema::create('games_owners', function($table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->integer('game_id');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This would be your User model:

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    protected $guarded = array();
    public static $rules = array();

    // User belongsToMany Game
    public function games()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Game', 'games_owners', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

And you game model:

```
class Game extends Eloquent 
{
    protected $guarded = array();
    public static $rules = array();

    // Game belongsToMany User
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'games_owners', 'game_id');
    }

    // Need to identify the owner user.
}
```

And then you'll be able to do things like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach($user->games as $game) {
    echo $game->name;
}
```

Comment: So, essentially, the Owner-Game relationship is a Many-To-Many. Correct?

Comment: Yes it is. Unless someone create a game for just one person, it will always be a many to many relation.